# Close all intents and close application

Tags: android, android-intent

I am a french student and I'm actually working on an Android project.
I would find a solution to close all intents of my application and, by the way, close my app.
I have try this but it don't works:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Veuillez confirmer");
    builder.setMessage("Etes-vous certain de vouloir quitter le jeu?");
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //GameActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            finish();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I have also tried System.exit(0), but I came back on my previous intent and I don't want it...
I have also tried finishAffinity() and finishAndRemoveTask() but they required a 21 or 16 API and I'am only 15.

Does anybody could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//its clear all 
intent you can also use this to go the last activity and there you kill your app 
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

in your login activity check

```
 if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
      android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(0);
   }
```